# Add custom adapter to moshi

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have an `interface Data` with a function called `toData()`. Different objects inherits from this `Data`.

Now I wrote an adapter which transform the result of `toData()` into an `string`

My custom adapter looks like this:

```
class Base64TypeAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String?): ByteArray? {
        return value?.toByteArray()
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: Data?): String? {
        return value?.toData()?.let { Base64.encodeToString(it.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP) }
    }
}
```

I created a Moshi builder

```
    private val proxyManMoshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(Base64ArrayTypeAdapter())
        .add(Base64TypeAdapter())
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

    val dataAdapter = proxyManMoshi.adapter<Base64TypeAdapter>(Data::class.java)
```

But when I call `dataAdapter.toJson()` the input parameter is `Base64TypeAdapter` instead of `Data`.

How do I mount an adapter correctly?

Comment: looks like you just need to do `proxyManMoshi.adapter<Data>(Data::class.java)`. if that doesn't work, i'd need to see your Data class and the other adapter classes you're talking about.